# Nvim Showing Vim :h Pages

Tags: vim, neovim

Nvim is showing Vim's help pages.

I am using nvim, and I am not sure if this is a problem, but when I type something like `:help colorscheme` I receive the information for configuring colorschemes for vim instead of nvim.

Please let me know either (1) how to fix this (2) or that I'm an idiot.

For example, it tells me to put the color files in `~/.vim/colors/`, which doesn't work. For nvim they go in `~/.config/nvim/colors`.

Comment: This is [still the case](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/syntax.txt#L4650) in latest NeoVim. The good thing about open source is that you can fix it yourself! Can I suggest that you should try to get this fixed and send NeoVim a Pull Request to get this merged?

Comment: I created this [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12085) for it. I thought of changing the paths in a PR, but much more of the help file information is different, so I suppose a better solution exists elsewhere. I could still do the pr later if I decide to.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neovim is a fork of Vim. It still retains much of original Vim data including a heap of help pages unmodified.

Simply don't pay attention to this. Maybe they fix it... some day.